# How to access API json data?

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have JSON data I m retrieving from an API https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/. I m able to access the object data with no problem. My issue comes when the API changes the JSON index e.g....data[0]. It ends up retrieving the wrong attribute data. I want to know how to track the API changes without having to manually change the index number.

This portion of code shows how I m currently accessing it.

```
 var url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" ;
          $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: url,

dataType: "json",
success: function(data){

switch(type){

  case "neo":

  var quantity = 1;
  price = data[7].price_usd;
break;
}
```

Comment: Walk the array and check the id. It would have been nice if the API had used the id as the key for the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use named key for the array from server side PHP:

```
$data = array("element_price"=> price_value, "element_product"=> prod);     
// and so on other values

echo json_encode($data);
```

Now retrieve from the `data` array instead of index 0,1,2...7 use like:

```
var quantity = 1;
price = data[element_price].price_usd;
```